# user.properties in /bin has no effect in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I will use user.properties to overwrite some properties in jmeter.properties.

Overwriting the properties **summariser.out** in jmeter.properties:

in jmeter.properties

```
summariser.out=true
```

in user.properties

```
summariser.out=false
```

In the apache doc is written:

> Note: You can define additional JMeter properties in the file defined
>   by the JMeter property user.properties which has the default value
>   user.properties. The file will be automatically loaded if it is found
>   in the current directory or if it is found in the JMeter bin
>   directory. Similarly, system.properties is used to update system
>   properties.

so, my user.properties is in **/bin** and I the property in jmeter.properties -> user.properties=user.properties.

I tried also to load manually like:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream is = getTempInputStream(userPropTempFilePath);
props.load(is);
is.close();
```

That all has no effect.

Some idea how to load user.properties in java and to check if the properties are loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the solution:

```
String userProp = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("user.properties", "");
    if (userProp.length() > 0) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            File file = JMeterUtils.findFile(userProp);
            if (file.canRead()) {
                log.info("Loading user properties from: "
                        + file.getCanonicalPath());
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                Properties tmp = new Properties();
                tmp.load(fis);
                jmeterProps.putAll(tmp);
                LoggingManager.setLoggingLevels(jmeterProps);//Do what would be done earlier
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("Error loading user property file: " + userProp, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.warn("There was problem closing file stream", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you put that code?  I'm having the exact same issue, but having trouble with the idea that code has to be written for this to be possible.  You've pointed out the exact same documentation I was looking at which implies that this ought to be trivial.